# Integration with differential forms

Tags: integration, vector-analysis, differential-forms

I'm trying to calculate this integral

$\int_0^{2π}{1 \over{(Acos^2t+Bsin^2t)^2}}dt$, where $A,B>0$ using differetntial forms.

I have calculated $\int_0^{2π}{1 \over{(Acos^2t+Bsin^2t)}}dt={2π\over {\sqrt{AB}}}$ (I hope it's correct) and tried using it but that squared part is messing with me and I've also tried showing the form $-{y\over{(x^2+y^2)^2}}dx+{x\over{(x^2+y^2)^2}}dy$ is closed, but it turned out it isn't. So I'm stuck.

Can you give me any hints but please not solutions?

Comment: You meant to have a $^2$ on the denominator in both places? As you pointed out, the $1$-form $\omega = \dfrac1{\sqrt{AB}}\dfrac{-y\,dx+x\,dy}{(x^2+y^2)^2} = \dfrac1{\sqrt{AB}}\dfrac{d\theta}{r^2}$ is certainly not closed, so there is no homotopy invariance. Is it only the presence of $2\pi$ in the answer that makes you look for this? (The standard way I would recommend is to convert this to a complex line integral and apply the Residue Theorem, but with the $^2$ exponent it becomes horrid.) BTW, your answer is correct when there's no $^2$ on the denominator, so I highly doubt it's correct.

Comment: In fact, by applying Green's (Stokes's) Theorem, we can see it cannot be correct. Your alleged answer is the integral of $\omega$ over the unit circle, which (for $A,B>1$) differs from the integral over the ellipse by $-2\iint_R \frac{dr\wedge d\theta}{r^3} = -2\iint_R \frac{dA}{r^4}<0$.

Comment: (I left out multiplicative factors of $1/\sqrt{AB}$ above, but it's sort of irrelevant.)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are saying. I did not provide an answer. My answer ${2π\over {\sqrt{AB}}}$ is indeed for the integral without the $^2$ on the denominator. I'm not trying to prove they are equal. I'm just trying to solve the first integral.

Comment: Ah, I had difficulty interpreting what you wrote. I have worked on this a while and don't see any easy solution. I tried putting in a parameter (this often works): $\omega_\mu = d\theta/r^{2\mu}$ and finding the derivative with respect to $\mu$ of $\int_C \omega_\mu$, but it leads me nowhere. I do not foresee any easy solution.

Comment: That's ok. Thank you for your time. I'll give it some more thought. If you come up with something let me know.

Comment: I got it. Differentiating the integral without $^2$ on the denominator, in both $A$ and $B$ directions and then adding the results we have the first integral.

Comment: Very cute! Well done.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you notice that $\cos^2t=\frac{1+\cos2t}{2}$ and $\sin^2t=\frac{1-\sin2t}{2}$, so your denorminator becomes $(A+B\cos2t)^2$ for some $A,B$. Then using changing of variable your denominator becomes $(A+B\cos t)^2$ and you calculate the integral over $[0,\pi]$ and times factor $1/2$. Now the denorminator becomes $(A^2+B^2)\cos^2(t+\theta)$ for some $\theta$ depending on $A$ and $B$. Finally using $(\tan t)'=\frac{1}{\cos^2 t}$ you have the antiderivative and get your result.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I'm trying to do. I want to use differential forms and homotopy to solve it and not integration techniques